# PHP displaying info from two seperate tables

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have a web page that has a user database, each user has a unique User ID. Now I have created a login page where it starts a session, and the session includes the user ID.

I also have an "update status" option where the user types in a status and it submits the status and the users Unique ID into a new table. So the table will have the Users ID and the status that the user put in.

Now I want to display the users status on a page, and I want to display the user's Username along with it. So basically the code must take the user ID from the status table and then match it with the user ID from the Users table, and from that it must give me the username  from the matching ID in the users table.

****FINAL WORKING CODE****

//Connect to mysql
mysql_connect("localhost","root","");

//connect to database 
mysql_select_db("users");

//query the database
$query = "select * \n"
    . " from status inner join users \n"
    . " on status.user_id = users.id\n ORDER BY users.id DESC";

//fetch results / convert results into an array

```
            $result = mysql_query($query);
            while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
                $s_firstname = $row['firstname'];
                $s_lastname = $row['lastname'];
                $s_status = $row['status']
```

}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I recommend spending some time learning about joins in sql. You would only need one SQL query, and it would be something like this...

```
select * 
  from status inner join users 
  on status.userid = users.userid
  where active = '1' and connect = '1'
```

**Edit:** Although using mysql functions is not recommended (see the note at the top of this page - https://www.php.net/mysql_query),  your lines should be like this..

```
$query = "select * from status inner join users on status.user_id = users.id where active = '1' and connect = '1'";

$result = mysql_query($query);

WHILE ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){

...  rest of your code....
```

Comment: Hi again, I edited the code above, when I run the query in MySQL the tables join perfectly, and align the username with the ID. But when I echo out the results in my PHP page, it gives me that warning.

Comment: You are missing a call to actually run the query - "$result = mysql_query($query);"   and then you pass $result into your call to mysql_fetch_array

But you should know that these mysql functions are deprecated.  You should be using PDO or mysqli.  http://uk3.php.net/mysql_query  And that will be too much to explain in a comment or an answer.  I suggest doing some research on http://uk1.php.net/pdo

Comment: No probs.  You could click the tick underneath the voting arrows next to my answer :)

Comment: Haha my bad, first time using this site.